# Reverse htaccess in subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

In the main public_html folder I have an htaccess file with this content:

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html
```

This basically enables .shtml files to be parsed.

Now, I have a subfolder where I **don't** want .shtml files to be parsed, and instead act like default where .html and .php files are parsed as properly.

I've tried having no htaccess in the subfolder, and the .php does not get parsed as .php.

I've tried using RemoveType and RemoveHandler to remove the .shtml parser, but that doesn't work.

Basically all combinations I've tried either results in 403, the page getting spit out as plaintext or it getting parsed as regular html with no php support.

This is the current htaccess in the subfolder:

```
RemoveType .shtml
RemoveHandler .shtml
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Which results in 403 Page Forbidden

Comment: You could try and set `default-handler` again inside the subfolder.

Comment: Tried "SetHandler default-handler .php" which results in Internal Server Error 500.

Comment: If you don't want a page to be parsed as shtml, why do you give it a shtml extension?

Comment: Oh I don't, it's just that it feels like .shtml has somehow "taken over" the whole folder and subfolder and in turn denys me from using php at all. This is why I'm trying to reverse the htaccess.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour your are seeing. The RemoveType and RemoveHandler are not necessary. If you are not serving shtml pages from that directory, the handler does nothing. I don't see why you would get 403 errors, unless they are generated by something else. I recommend looking through your Apache error log if you can view that and see if you can find any clue to this behaviour there.

Comment: Have you posted the full .htaccess files as they appear on your server? Do the php files in your subfolder work if you rename your .htaccess files to .donotreadmeapache?

Comment: PHP works fine if I remove/rename the htaccess containing the shtml. I've sent a ticket to my host and we'll see if they can aid me in this.